Thingsboard sequential updates on docker - how do I specify the intermediate versions
I’m running Thingsboard CE 3.6.1 using docker on Ubuntu.
I’d like to upgrade to a more recent version. Previous questions have indicated that sequential upgrades are preferable (3.6.1 > 3.6.2 > 3.6.3 > 3.7, not 3.6.1 > 3.7)
How do I specify the current and target versions for the upgrade script when running in docker?
I tried specifying a Thingsboard CE image version in docker compose (thingsboard/tb-postgres:3.6.2), but the script tried pulling :latest
